Why does the Septuagint us ph for the name Philistines?
Reading the ever-surprising Timeline of the name Palestine, I noticed that the Egyptian, Assyrian, and biblical Hebrew have a "P" as the first consonant of the names equivalent to Peleshet/Pelishtim; and that the Greek similarly used Palaistinoi, with a Π, since the 5th century BCE. (The Hebrew reading is based on the later addition of Dagesh diacritics, but these are used consistently).
Then, comes my question, why does the Septuagint use Φ or ph, when it transliterates the name? Might it be a meaningful choice? Could this show more accuracy than older transliterations? Or could this be a pun or an intentional corruption of the original form?
(Trying my best to follow the phonology of Koine Greek, there doesn't seem to be any pressure to transition "p" to "f". Although, it seems something similar happened with 'Pharaoh'. Hebrew did gain an "f" sound at around this time, but I don't think it would be used at this position)

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

If you don't get an answer here, wait a while and then ask the question on Latin Language Stack Exchange, which despite its name also answers questions about Greek.

I suggest you look at the well-known effect of Grimm's law where, as time progresses /p/ morphs into /f/ among other effects.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_law

To follow up, this does not seem to be an intentional choice. According to this there was a tendency but no  rule for these transliterations.  According to a more detailed attempt, it followed Greek conventions as they changed, and can be used to date or provenance Septuagint texts. The letter φ went from representing an aspirated, /pʰ/, to a fricative, /f/. The former consonant seems close enough to] the expected /p/.

The use of Φ (ph) in the Septuagint’s transliteration of the name Philistines could be due to:
Phonological Changes in Greek:

The Greek language underwent pronunciation changes during the Koine
Greek period, from about 300 BC to 400 AD. At the beginning of the
period, the pronunciation was close to Classical Greek, while at the
end it was almost identical to Modern Greek. [1]

One of these changes was the transition of the letter Φ from representing an aspirated /pʰ/ to a fricative /f/.

The consonants φ, θ and χ, which were initially pronounced as
aspirates /pʰ/, /tʰ/ and /kʰ/ , developed into fricatives /f/, [θ]
and [x~ç].There is evidence for fricative θ in Laconian in the 5th
century BC, but this is unlikely to have influenced Koine Greek,
which is largely based on Ionic-Attic. According to Allen, the first
clear evidence for fricative φ and θ in Koine Greek dates from the
1st century AD in Latin Pompeian inscriptions, which transcribe φ and
θ with f: [1]

I'll also note that many of:

These changes seem widely attested from the 2nd century BC in
Egyptian Greek, and in the early 2nd century AD in learned Attic
inscriptions; it is therefore likely that they were already common in
the 2nd century BC and generalized no later than the 2nd century AD.
[1]

So, the transition from “p” to “f” in the Septuagint’s transliteration of Palestine might not be an intentional choice, but rather a reflection of phonetic changes in the Greek language over time
This could explain why the Septuagint, which was translated during this period, uses Φ for the name Philistines.

As for the term “Palestine”. Something interesting is that it may have originated as a Greek pun on the translations of “Israel” and the "Land of the Philistines" [2]. The Greek Palaistinê and the Latin Palaestina appear frequently in ancient literature, but for the most part, they appear to refer not to the Land of the Philistines, but to the Land of Israel [2]

Thank you. The theory under 2 is a rather spurious one, and is the reason I went looking for the more strictly linguistic evidence.
